# Extract number of days by year with beginning and end dates that may or may not span years

Tags: r, date, date-range, lubridate

Hi I am trying to extract the number of days into variables Days2010:Days2015. The begdate and enddate may or may not span a year or more.

```
 df <- data.frame(BEGIN_DT = c("12/12/2013", "01/14/2013", "02/12/2012", "09/23/2013", "10/18/2013"),
             END_DT = c("09/04/2015", "06/01/2013", "04/01/2013", "11/09/2015",  "11/12/2014"))
 rownames(df) <- c(16:20)
 df$BEGIN_DT <- as.Date(df$BEGIN_DT, "%m/%d/%Y")
 df$END_DT <- as.Date(df$END_DT, "%m/%d/%Y")


     `BEGIN_DT     END_DT
     16 2013-12-12 2015-09-04
     17 2013-01-14 2013-06-01
     18 2012-02-12 2013-04-01
     19 2013-09-23 2015-11-09
     20 2013-10-18 2014-11-12`

    So, for row 16, I would end up with 
    Days2012 = 19; 
    Days2013 = 365; 
    Days2014 = 365; 
    Days2015 = 246.
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one solution assuming you have things in `df`:

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) {
               dates <- seq.Date(as.Date(x[1]), as.Date(x[2]), by = 'days')
               table(format(dates, '%Y'))
               }
      )
```

You go through each row, create a sequence of dates, extract years and do crosstab. This provides you in a list format. You can modify the output format to suit your need.

You can get it into a data frame as follows, assuming you saved the above output into a list called `l`:

```
maxLength <- max(sapply(l, length))
as.data.frame(t(sapply(l, function(x)
                            c(x, rep(NA, maxLength - length(x)))
                      )
                )
             )

   2013 2014 2015
16   20  365  247
17  139   NA   NA
18  324   91   NA
19  100  365  313
20   75  316   NA
```

Comment: The apply command already provides a list, I added code to convert to data frame as an option.

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks so much for your very helpful answer!

Comment: Yes, I finally figured that out. Thank you. I've got it in a data frame now. Now I just need to apply this to my actual df. Thanks again!